# OpenMP gives (core dumped) | Laplace method in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to write code for parallel calculation of the determinant of the matrix using the Laplace method in OpenMP, but I ran into an error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Where did I make a mistake?

This is the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

long double **nowaMacierz(int stopien);

void usunMacierz(long double **macierz);

long double metodaLaplace(long double **macierz, int stopien, int count);

int main() {
    long double **macierz;
    int stopien;
    int count = 1;
    int nr_wiersza, nr_kolumny;

    printf("Proszę podać stopień macierzy n=");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &stopien);
    macierz = nowaMacierz(stopien);
    for (nr_wiersza = 0; nr_wiersza < stopien; nr_wiersza++)
        for (nr_kolumny = 0; nr_kolumny < stopien; nr_kolumny++) {
            printf("A[%d,%d]=", nr_wiersza, nr_kolumny);
            fscanf(stdin, "%Lf", &macierz[nr_wiersza][nr_kolumny]);
        }
    printf("det(A) = %Lf\n", metodaLaplace(macierz, stopien, count));
    usunMacierz(macierz);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

long double **nowaMacierz(int stopien) {
    long double **macierz;
    int nr_wiersza;

    macierz = (long double **) calloc(stopien, sizeof(long double *));
    *macierz = (long double *) calloc(stopien * stopien, sizeof(long double));

    // Przydzielone adresy komórek pamięci są segragowane, tak by utworzyły tablicę dwuwymiarową
    for (nr_wiersza = 1; nr_wiersza < stopien; nr_wiersza++)
        *(macierz + nr_wiersza) = *(macierz + nr_wiersza - 1) + stopien;
    return macierz;
}

void usunMacierz(long double **macierz) {
    free(*macierz), free(macierz);
    return;
}

long double metodaLaplace(long double **macierz, int stopien, int count) {
    long double **dopelnienie;   
    int nr_wiersza, nr_kolumny;
    int nr_kolumny_dop, nr_kolumny_mac;
    long double det = 0.00;   

    printf("test");

    if (count == 0) {
        printf("sekwenc");
        if (stopien <= 2)
            return macierz[0][0] * (stopien > 1 ? macierz[1][1] : 1) -
                   (stopien > 1 ? macierz[0][1] * macierz[1][0] : 0);

        dopelnienie = nowaMacierz(stopien - 1);

        for (nr_kolumny = 0; nr_kolumny < stopien; nr_kolumny++) {
            for (nr_kolumny_dop = 0, nr_kolumny_mac = 0;
                 nr_kolumny_dop < stopien - 1; nr_kolumny_dop++, nr_kolumny_mac++) {
                nr_kolumny_mac += (nr_kolumny_mac == nr_kolumny ? 1
                                                                : 0);
                for (nr_wiersza = 0; nr_wiersza < stopien - 1; nr_wiersza++)
                    dopelnienie[nr_wiersza][nr_kolumny_dop] = macierz[nr_wiersza + 1][nr_kolumny_mac];
            }
            // det = ?(aij * (-1)^i+j * Aij)
            det += (macierz[0][nr_kolumny] * (long double) pow(-1.0, 1.0 + nr_kolumny + 1.0) *
                    metodaLaplace(dopelnienie, stopien - 1, count - 1));
        }
    } else {
        printf("parallel %d", omp_get_num_threads());
        // Wyznacznik stopnia co najwyżej 2. zostanie obliczony z definicji
        if (stopien <= 2)
            return macierz[0][0] * (stopien > 1 ? macierz[1][1] : 1) -
                   (stopien > 1 ? macierz[0][1] * macierz[1][0] : 0);

#pragma omp parallel private(nr_wiersza, nr_kolumny, nr_kolumny_dop, nr_kolumny_mac, dopelnienie,stopien, macierz)
        dopelnienie = nowaMacierz(stopien - 1);

#pragma omp parallel for
        for (nr_kolumny = 0; nr_kolumny < stopien; nr_kolumny++) {
            for (nr_kolumny_dop = 0, nr_kolumny_mac = 0;
                 nr_kolumny_dop < stopien - 1; nr_kolumny_dop++, nr_kolumny_mac++) {
                nr_kolumny_mac += (nr_kolumny_mac == nr_kolumny ? 1
                                                                : 0); 
                for (nr_wiersza = 0; nr_wiersza < stopien - 1; nr_wiersza++)
                    dopelnienie[nr_wiersza][nr_kolumny_dop] = macierz[nr_wiersza + 1][nr_kolumny_mac];
            }
            // det = ?(aij * (-1)^i+j * Aij)
            det += (macierz[0][nr_kolumny] * (long double) pow(-1.0, 1.0 + nr_kolumny + 1.0) *
                    metodaLaplace(dopelnienie, stopien - 1, count - 1));
        }
    }

    usunMacierz(dopelnienie);
    return det;
}
```

The problem appeared when using a variable used to assign values from recursion, in "#pragma omp parallel private".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `#pragma omp parallel` section applies to to next statement. The first is applied the line `dopelnienie = nowaMacierz(stopien - 1);` which is certainly not what you want since you put private variables that does not appear in the statement. In the second one, some variable like `nr_kolumny_mac` are unprotected which causes a race condition. Maybe you missed to use { ... }. If so, please note that a `#pragma omp parallel for` is equivalent to `#pragma omp parallel` + `#pragma omp for`, and having two nested parallel for is generally a bad idea and rarely wanted.

Comment: Note also that variables used in `private` clause are uninitialized, so `stopien` is uninitialized in your case. This may be a potential reason for a segmentation fault. You may have intended to use the `firstprivate` clause. You should 1) turn on all compiler warnings and treat them as errors, 2) define your variables in their minimum required scope, 3) check your code for data race: e.g. there is a race condition when increasing `det`.

Comment: Are you sure that the serial code is working properly? Your 2D array allocation function (`nowaMacierz`) seems to be flawed.

Comment: I'm with @Laci : this `**` stuff to get double indexing is very tricky and probably wrong in your code. Allocate everything one-dimensional, and use a macro `#define INDEX(i,j) (i)*N+(j)` to do indexing.